# Lattice Plot - Add lines through mean of y values

Tags: r, lattice

I want to print a `lattice::xyplot` with grouped points and lines, but I have multiple `y` values for many of the individual `x` values in each group.  I want a segmented line printed, so that for each `x` value, it passes through the mean of the relevant `y` values in each group.

Here's an example:

Using this data:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x=sample(6, 20, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(20), g=factor(sample(2, 20, replace=TRUE)))
# Shift one group
d$y[d$g==2] = d$y[d$g==2] + 5
```

I've shifted one group so the lines are more visually appealing.

A scatter plot looks like this:

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data=d, groups=g)
```

[image]

Just adding lines is a real mess:

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data=d, groups=g, type=c('p','l'))
```

[image]

It's a bit better if you sort the `x` values, but still not what I want:

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data=d[order(d$x),], groups=g, type=c('p','l'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `panel.superpose` and then do the aggregation in the group panel function. For example

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data=d, groups=g, panel=function(...) {
    panel.xyplot(...);
    panel.superpose(..., panel.groups=function(x, y, col.line, ...) {
        dd <- aggregate(y~x, data.frame(x,y), mean)
        panel.xyplot(x=dd$x, y=dd$y, col=col.line, type="l")
    })
})
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data=d, groups=g,
       panel = function(x, y, subscripts, groups, ...) {     
         grp <- as.numeric(groups[subscripts])
         col <- trellis.par.get()$superpose.symbol$col
         panel.xyplot(x, y, subscripts=subscripts, groups=groups, ...)
         for (g in unique(grp)) {
           sel <- g == grp
           m   <- aggregate(list(y=y[sel]), list(x=x[sel]), FUN=mean)
           panel.lines(m$x, m$y, col=col[g])
         }
       }
)
```

[image]

So what's going on here?  `subscripts` is the list of subscripts for each panel.  In my small example there is no conditioning, so it is `1:20`.  Likewise `groups` is the list of groups for the panel.  Again, there is one panel, so this is `d$g`.

`grp` is then the index of each group in its factor.

`col` is the set of colors, indexed in the `panel.lines` function to select the same color as the points.

For each group, an average is computed for each `x` value in that group, and that is passed to `panel.lines` for the coordinates.

Comment: Is there a better way?